# Mui Grid Toolbar Filter Button

Tags: reactjs, filter, material-ui, datagrid, mui-x-data-grid

I want to show to users **filter bar** when my Datagrid component created. When my component created, Users should see Datagrid as below (as if filtering button was clicked)

[image]

The codes of the Mui Datagrid component I use are down below.

```js
<DataGrid
  rows={tableRows}
  columns={tableColumns}
  components={{ Toolbar: ReportRenderToolbar }}
  checkboxSelection
  disableRowSelectionOnClick
/>
```

Custom Toolbar component is:

```js
import React from "react";

import {
  GridToolbarContainer,
  GridToolbarFilterButton,
} from "@mui/x-data-grid";

const ReportRenderToolbar = () => {
  return (
    <GridToolbarContainer>
      <GridToolbarFilterButton />
    </GridToolbarContainer>
  );
};

export default ReportRenderToolbar;
```

Is there any props I can pass to `<GridToolbarFilterButton />`?
And how can I show filter bar above the datagrid?

Answer (score -1):

To pass props down to your custom components.

The `components` prop is **deprecated**, see [overriding components](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/components/#overriding-components).

Instead you can use the new **slots**.

Provide the `DataGrid` with a `slots` prop for your custom components and pass props with `slotProps`.

```js
<DataGrid
  rows={rows}
  columns={columns}
  slots={{
    toolbar: ReportRenderToolbar,
  }}
  slotProps={{
    toolbar: { counter: rows.length },
  }}
/>
```

Custom Toolbar

To position the filter panel a row lower you can add a negative `top` value.

```js
const ReportRenderToolbar = (props) => {
  console.log(props);

  return (
    <GridToolbarContainer sx={{ top: -120 }}>
      <GridToolbarFilterButton />
    </GridToolbarContainer>
  );
};
```

Comment: Its not working if i use slots. I think i need to use components. Is it about version? I use 5.14